# 3 clicks with a confirm javascript window?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi its taking 3 clicks to excute any command with my javascript confirm prompt. All my code is nested in a handle-request ajax function. Here is my code, I dont know why its doing this?

```
closeButton.onclick = function() {
    node.setData('alpha', 0, 'end');
    node.eachAdjacency(function(adj) {
      adj.setData('alpha', 0, 'end');
        var requestone = createRequest();
        var deletenode = node.id;
        var vars = "deletenode=" + encodeURIComponent(deletenode);
           requestone.open("POST", "deletenode.php", true);
           requestone.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this species from the Database?')) {
           requestone.onreadystatechange = function()
           {
           handleRequest(requestone);
           };
          requestone.send(vars);
          fd.fx.animate({
         modes: ['node-property:alpha',
               'edge-property:alpha'],
         duration: 500
        }); 
 } else
{
  // Do nothing!
 }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean that, it required 3 clicks. You have to be wait until the operation is complete. Then only you will get the response. That means readyState becomes 4.

readyState is one of the property of HTTPRequest. It indicates the current state of the object.

There are 5 states. 
0 - uninitialized (UNSENT) 
1 - loading (OPENED) 
2 - loaded (HEADERS_RECEIVED) 
3 - interactive (LOADING) 
4 - complete (DONE)

Comment: how can I get it to just do 1 click?